# How to filter dateformat on HTML code in angularjs

Tags: html, date, datetimepicker

This is how i show data on my html page.

It show output 2016:05:23, but i want 23:05:2016.

`<div class="abc">{{loginDatetime}}</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular, you can used the filter for that filtering date like:

```
<div class="abc">{{loginDatetime | date:'dd:MM:yyyy'}}</div>
```

You can use this link:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date